# Haskell function which takes a list and return tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have ordederd to make a function, which takes a list ex [3,4,6,1,29] and returns a list of tuples [(3,4),(4,6),(6,1),(1,29)]

Comment: See [this set of guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812) for asking about homework. Neither of your questions really fits the bill.

Comment: Hmm... every body is closing the question... try adding homework tag and before that try understanding list comprehensions in haskell

Answer (score 3):

This is a very easy question, it's really hard to help without defeating the purpose...

If you are allowed to use predifined functions, there is already one which can do almost all work for you (if you don't know which one, try finding it with http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ ). Take a step back and think about the easier question how to produce a list [(3,3),(4,4),(6,6),(1,1),(29,29)].

If you can't use predefined functions, then recursion is your friend: What do you need to do for an empty list? What for a list with one element? With two elements?

Without any own effort I can't give more hints. If you're stuck, extend your question and show what you already got, and we'll try to help.